# Looping over json object in flask

Tags: python, json, api, loops, flask

```
@app.route('/parseJSON',methods=['GET','POST'])
def parseJSON():
    input_name = request.form["search"]
    url = "https://api.github.com/search/users?q={0}".format(input_name)
    loadurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(loadurl.read().decode(loadurl.info().getparam('charset') or 'utf-8'))
    item=data["items"][0]["avatar_url"]
    return item
```

This is just spitting out the avatar_url which is great. But now i want to show the username along with a link to the profile. I think this could be done with a loop somehow but I'm still very new to Python/Flask and not really sure how this would be done. The final output should be as follows

```
Username: "login"
Profile: "url"
img: "avatar_url"
```

This should update everything someone enters a new value in the search form

```
@app.route('/search',methods=['GET','POST'])
def search():
    return render_template("search.html")

<form action="/parseJSON" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

i plan on putting the avatar_url into a html img tag and displaying it.

Comment: Presumably this is Python 3? `getparam()` takes a default, by the way, and you can use `get_charset()`.

Comment: What is the *expected outcome* here? A list of URLs? How should that be returned to the requester? As one long string?

Comment: Then you don't need to decode the response at all.

Comment: Then how do i do it?

Comment: I already posted an answer. Can you please tell us what output you were expecting? What should be returned to the browser here?

Answer (score 4):

You can extract *all* urls with a list comprehension:

```
items = [item['avatar_url'] for item in data["items"]]
```

but in Flask you do need to return a valid response. Usually that means you return a string, so you'd need to join those URLs:

```
return '\n'.join(items)
```

You could also return a JSON list:

```
from flask import jsonify

# ....

return jsonify(items=items)
```

This returns a JSON object with the key `'items'` pointing to the list; the [`jsonify()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.json.jsonify) creates a proper `Response()` object with the correct `application/json` header set for you.

In Python 2, you don't need to decode the JSON response; GitHub sticks to the JSON RFC and returns UTF-encoded data:

```
@app.route('/parseJSON',methods=['GET','POST'])
def parseJSON():
    input_name = request.form["search"]
    url = "https://api.github.com/search/users?q={0}".format(input_name)
    loadurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(loadurl)
    items = [item['avatar_url'] for item in data["items"]]
    return '\n'.join(items)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import json
>>> url = "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=martijn"
>>> loadurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
>>> data = json.load(loadurl)
>>> items = [item['avatar_url'] for item in data["items"]]
>>> print '\n'.join(items)
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/107915?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/623509?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/431452?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/46626?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/46775?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/180840?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/245275?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/670951?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/121401?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/506862?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/627350?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2605679?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/4040870?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/120452?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/167455?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/965129?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/515239?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/197477?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/178230?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/490579?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1426964?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/327472?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/193881?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/907436?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/6215449?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/580421?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/3951973?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/426811?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1290310?v=3
https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1652861?v=3
```

If you want to pull out more information into strings, I'd use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
template = '''\
Username: "{i[login]}"
Profile: "{i[url]}"
img: "{i[avatar_url]}"
'''
items = [template.format(i=item) for item in data["items"]]
return '\n'.join(items)
```

Each `{}` placeholder pulls a different key from the item passed in with the `i` keyword argument.

Demo with the same search:

```
>>> template = '''\
... Username: "{i[login]}"
... Profile: "{i[url]}"
... img: "{i[avatar_url]}"
... '''
>>> items = [template.format(i=item) for item in data["items"]]
>>> print '\n'.join(items)
Username: "martijn"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/martijn"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/107915?v=3"

Username: "martijnvermaat"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/martijnvermaat"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/623509?v=3"

Username: "mvdkleijn"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/mvdkleijn"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/431452?v=3"

Username: "dashorst"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/dashorst"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/46626?v=3"

Username: "mjpieters"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/mjpieters"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/46775?v=3"

Username: "karianna"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/karianna"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/180840?v=3"

Username: "Mpdreamz"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/Mpdreamz"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/245275?v=3"

Username: "Swaagie"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/Swaagie"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/670951?v=3"

Username: "maerteijn"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/maerteijn"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/121401?v=3"

Username: "MartijnB"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/MartijnB"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/506862?v=3"

Username: "MartijnR"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/MartijnR"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/627350?v=3"

Username: "Speedy1985"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/Speedy1985"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2605679?v=3"

Username: "Azeirah"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/Azeirah"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/4040870?v=3"

Username: "mvexel"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/mvexel"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/120452?v=3"

Username: "martijnboland"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/martijnboland"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/167455?v=3"

Username: "Martijnc"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/Martijnc"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/965129?v=3"

Username: "Pixelstudio"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/Pixelstudio"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/515239?v=3"

Username: "mvmaasakkers"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/mvmaasakkers"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/197477?v=3"

Username: "martijndeh"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/martijndeh"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/178230?v=3"

Username: "Zegnat"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/Zegnat"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/490579?v=3"

Username: "mgussekloo"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/mgussekloo"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1426964?v=3"

Username: "faassen"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/faassen"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/327472?v=3"

Username: "martijnthe"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/martijnthe"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/193881?v=3"

Username: "MartijnKaijser"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/MartijnKaijser"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/907436?v=3"

Username: "ByteHazard"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/ByteHazard"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/6215449?v=3"

Username: "martijnvg"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/martijnvg"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/580421?v=3"

Username: "MartijnWoudstra"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/MartijnWoudstra"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/3951973?v=3"

Username: "MartijnDwars"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/MartijnDwars"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/426811?v=3"

Username: "cornips"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/cornips"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1290310?v=3"

Username: "martijn94"
Profile: "https://api.github.com/users/martijn94"
img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1652861?v=3"
```

Comment: This is good but i just want to loop thru and get the username/avatar_url/url

Comment: @user3079589: Again, Flask needs to return a *proper response*. You can't just return a list. What is the response you are expecting? JSON data, a string, something else? Please be **explicit**. You may want to update your question to include that information.

Comment: im expecting a string with just username the avatar and profile url

Comment: @KittenCornBall: with commas between them? Tabs, colons, newlines?

Comment: Looking for new lines

Comment: @KittenCornBall: can you please add a sample output to your question then?

Comment: So with my original post im just returning the login for the first person in the json. But what i want now is the login the avatar and the avatar. So that would look something like 
Username: ----
link: ----
avatar:---

Comment: @KittenCornBall: please do edit your question then; it can then be reopened.